# connect third party service to google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I want to develop some application for my Google Home but before I start coding I have to be sure if I can connect the Google Home with third party service for example:

- Paypal
- Amazon

I mean all service API that need an authentication like paypal popup or facebook popup or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [Account Linking with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2) to have them log into your service through an OAuth service you control (such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/)'s). That OAuth service can require them to login using Paypal or Facebook's sign-in services.